# Sequence $f_n(\omega)$ is not convergent for any $\omega\in\Omega$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega =[0,1]$ with $\mathscr{F}$ the Borel sets on $[0,1]$ and $P(d\omega )=d\omega$. Every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be written as $n=2^h+k$ for unique $h\ge 0,k\ge0$ and $k<2^h$.

We have $\displaystyle A_n=[k2^{-h}, (k+1)2^{-h})$ and let $\displaystyle f_n=1_{A_n}$.

I've shown that the sequence $f_n$ converges to $f=0$ in $p^{th}$ mean for any $p$, $1\le p <\infty$:
$$\displaystyle E|f_n-f|^p=E|1_{A_n}-0|^p=\int 1_{A_n}^p dP=\int_{\frac{n}{2^h}-1}^{\frac{n_1}{2^h}-1}1^pdP=\frac{n+1}{2^h}-1-\frac{n}{2^h}+1=\frac{1}{2^h}=\frac{1}{n-k}$$
which goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

My problem is, I don't know how to show the sequence $f_n(\omega)$ is not convergent for any $\omega\in\Omega =[0,1]$.

$$\forall\omega\in\Omega, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(\omega )=\lim 1_{[n/2^h-1, (n+1)/2^h-1)(\omega )}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $n=2^h$ to $n=2^{h} +2^{h}-1$, the $A_{n}$'s partition $[0,1]$.

Comment: So since n goes to infinity, the indicator function would become 0? When the question asks show the sequence $f_n(\omega )$ is not convergent for any $\omega\in [0,1]$, does it mean to show the limit of $f_n$ doesn't converge or $P(\{\omega\colon f_n\ne f\})>0$? thank you

Comment: @brenna The point is that $f_{n}(\omega)$ converges iff $\omega$ is eventually in or not in all the $A_n$'s, but these $A_n$'s are 'marching along' the unit interval, and getting smaller and smaller, so infinitely often $\omega$ will be both in and not in $A_n$'s.